# codeigniter cli is not working showing errors with ./system/core/Log.php on line 131

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to use codeigniter function via cli but it is showing me error

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Msg_controller extends CI_Controller {
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function send_in_background($key_with_info){
       echo "working";
       log_message("error","Key ".$key_with_info);
    }
}
```

**CALLING IT LIKE -:**

php index.php cli/msg_controller/send_in_background  '12547'

**ERROR**

PHP Warning:  mkdir(): Invalid path in /var/www/html/pro/system/core/Log.php on line 131

If i am calling same function from browser it is working fine.

```
http://localhost/pro/cli/msg_controller/send_in_background/12547
```

Comment: It's not an error, but a warning? Check owner and permissions on the file/folder. User/group is different when executing in browser compared to executing in terminal.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to run via CLI is

```
 php path/to/index.php controller method params
```

In your case:

```
  php index.php msg_controller send_in_background 12547
```

Give that a try